# extracting variables from an array JSON, Xcode

Tags: arrays, json, xcode

im very new to this XCODE objective C, browse through the forum cant get what i need. im trying to extract a specific value from an array. im using teleduino, web service, just incase you know about it. so ermm.. im not sure why im not getting the output for this value "328-0.6.9" as shown in the figure attached. i dont need the other data just that one data.

Output from xcode

```js
2015-03-20 01:17:19.987 APItest[1686:56954] Succeeded! Received 100 bytes of data
2015-03-20 01:17:19.988 APItest[1686:56954] key: status
2015-03-20 01:17:19.988 APItest[1686:56954] value: 200
2015-03-20 01:17:19.989 APItest[1686:56954] key: message
2015-03-20 01:17:19.989 APItest[1686:56954] value: OK
2015-03-20 01:17:19.989 APItest[1686:56954] key: response
2015-03-20 01:17:19.990 APItest[1686:56954] value: {
    result = 1;
    time = "0.57582592964172";
    values =     (
        "328-0.6.9"
    );
```

my code

```js
    // convert to JSON
    NSError *myError = nil;
    NSDictionary *res = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:self.responseData options:NSJSONReadingMutableLeaves error:&myError];
    
    // show all values
    for(id key in res) {
        
        id values = [res objectForKey:key];
        
        NSString *keyAsString = (NSString *)key;
        NSString *valueAsString = (NSString *)values;
        
       NSLog(@"key: %@", keyAsString);
        NSLog(@"value: %@", valueAsString);
    }
   
     //extract specific value...
    NSArray *value = [res objectForKey:@""];
    
    for (NSDictionary *values in value) {
        NSString *icon = [values objectForKey:@"icon"];
        NSLog(@"icon: %@", icon);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your logs, values is an array of strings. Please try following:

```
//extract specific value...
NSArray * values = [res objectForKey:@"values"];

for (NSString *value in values) {

    NSLog(@"icon: %@", value);
}
```

Comment: hmm... doesnt  seems to work... i think im gonna re-write everything.. i'll update this post when i succeed.